# Chr (169) not giving copyright symbol

Tags: windows, ms-access, chr

I have an mdb split FE and BE which on my Windows 10 / Office 365 Acess is giving © for Chr(169).

On my client's machine (recent update to Windows 10) with Office 2013, Access is giving � (Actually, in the Immediate window it looks a 1 with an umlaut, then an upside down question mark then a superscript 1/2) for Chr(169).

In the Immediate window on the client's machine, Asc("©") gives 176 instead of 169.

It seems the character maps are different between the two machines, although when I go to the Character Map app, for Arial and Times New Roman it shows © as being 169.

How do I get the client's machine to match mine?

The first thing I was recommended to do was an Office Repair.  After this, in the Immediate window I get a different value each time I do

?asc("©")

48 then 16 then 72 then 112 then 144 and so on, random numbers.

This is the same whether I copy a copyright symbol from MS Word or Character Map App.

Actually, when I paste the copyright symbol into the Immedate Window, it comes through as A(with circumflex over it)©. Does that help/mean anything?

Also the £ sign has an empty square next to it.

Anyone got any ideas?  Office issue?  Windows issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `AscW` when using non-ASCII characters.

A copyright sign is not part of standard ASCII, so may or may not be represented in the codepage Windows uses, depending on locale settings.

`AscW` uses unicode instead of the Windows codepage, which means it will reliably produce the same result.

Also, never store non-ASCII characters in VBA. If you need a specific character, you can look up the codepoint and use `ChrW` to generate the string. For multiple characters, I recommend you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949328/7296893), or store them outside of VBA.

Then, as for the immediate window, that also does not support unicode characters, so you can't trust what gets displayed there. Nor does `MsgBox`. This makes debugging a pain. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210316/7296893) for having a messagebox with unicode support.