# Joining a column that contains non-ansi characters in Access

Tags: ms-access

I need to compare two tables inside a Microsoft Access database.

Since this is a one time thing, I didn't want to look for a software to do that, instead I wanted to do that by creating queries to show me the rows that only exist in one of the tables.

So I created two queries, query 1 is showing me the rows of table 1 that are **not** present in table 2 and query 2 is showing me the rows of table 2 that are **not** present in table 1.

In both queries I do a `LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN` on all of the primary key columns and only return the rows of one table, when the primary key columns in the other table are `NULL`.

This worked the way I expected it, but for one row.

Checking the content of this one row in both tables I couldn't find a difference, there were no leading or tailing spaces, there were no `TAB`s instead of spaces and I couldn't find other differences of that kind, believe me I tried.

Because I didn't know what else to do, I just replaced some non-ansi characters (german umlauts ä and ü) with their ansi counter parts, and suddenly my queries showed no differences anymore.
Replacing the ansi characters back to their non-ansi counter parts one by one, I found out, that the `JOIN`s don't seem work when there's an "ä" present in the joined column. If the column contains an "ü" instead of an "ä" (same place in the string), then the `JOIN`s work.

How is that possible? Is that a known bug of Access? Or is it a feature? How can I rely on working `JOIN`s? Is there a setting I have to change?

Comment: Check the binary content of the string. ü can be 0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS + a normal U, or 00FC LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIARESIS. These are different, the first even takes 2 more bytes to store in Access), so won't get recognized as identical, even though they display as identical.

Comment: How do I check the content of a string column on binary level in Access?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51949328/7296893), the UnicodeToByteArray function. You can adjust that to just return the bytes as hex.

Comment: I got both strings (the ones with the umlauts) out of  the tables in a VBA module and compared them there... they are considered equal. Nevertheless they are not considered equal in the `JOIN`.

Comment: That's very strange, if they're fully identical (byte-for-byte), it should just work. Alternatively, if they're truly identical, you can perform a binary comparison: `ON STRCOMP(Field1, Field2, 0) = 0`. Note that you should not paste unicode in VBA (either the immediate window or a module) to check if they're identical, since the VBE doesn't support unicode and thus casts the characters to ANSI (which does allow umlauts depending on your locale).