# Why my pasted link turns into "???" for the Japanese Characters using VBA Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I have a question regarding VBA macro, I've tried to write a sample code and it happens that Japanese characters are resulting to "???" when I copy then paste it to my VBA code.

**Expected Result of pasted link:**

```
C:\Users\username\folder\Global - 新しいフォルダ - Sample
```

**Actual output of pasted link in vba:**

```
C:\Users\username\folder\Global - ???????-GREAT????? - Sample
```

I tried to debug it but it has the same output, may I know what seems to be the problem? Below picture was my code and I also checked the region of my machine and it was already set in Japanese(Japan) format.

[image]

Thank you in advance for the solutions and other ways to fix it. I will appreciate it all :)

Comment: There is no picture (below or somewhere else). Anyhow, code pictures are not good to be shown, since you can paste the code  text, as it is... It is, anyhow,  more complicated to  make a picture, instead o pasting it. Please, edit the question and paste the code in discussion.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that I not included the picture, it is now updated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try changing your Office default display language?

Also you can try this:
[Using Multiple Languages In VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948424/using-multiple-language-english-chinese-japanese-in-vba)

Comment: Thank you @BatuhanGez for the answer, it seems that my Japanese Language in display language hat not been installed yet. I'll come back here for the updates in accordance of your solution. Thank you so much :)